# Get AccessibilityService Events even if Interruptions are disabled (device muted) on lollipop?

Tags: java, android

I noticed that my AccessibilityService doesn't get notified if lollipop's notifications are set to "No interruptions" (muted) even if the notification is shown in the statusbar. Does someone know how to get these notification regardless of the notification state of the phone?